# How can I create an image with text on the side (left or right) with proper spacing in between

Tags: html, css

How can I copy the layout of this page?

I want to have an image with text on the right side of it but has to have a small space between them so they don't look too crowded and an image with text on the left. See sample page attached.

```
[Image] -space- [Text ]
[Text ] -space- [Image]
[Image] -space- [Text ]
```

[Image With Text Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjMrr.png)

Answer (score 1):

This a link only answer, because the link describes it perfectly:

https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_float.asp

The examples use CSS `'Flow'` to flow the image `left` or `right`.

You can then use CSS `margin` or `padding` to create a distance between text and image.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please use the power of flex for the equal size and spacing between the content.flex is very handy and easy to use.
I hope it will work for you.

You can use the .my-space-between class for margin .

```css
.myflex{display:flex; justify-content:space-between; }
.my-inner-item div{flex:1; }
.my-space-between{flex:.1;  }
```

```html
<div class="myflex">
<div class="my-inner-item">my image will be here </div>
<div class="my-space-between"></div>
<div class="my-inner-item">my text will be here</div>

</div>

<div class="myflex">
<div class="my-inner-item">my image will be here </div>
<div class="my-space-between"></div>
<div class="my-inner-item">my text will be here</div>

</div>

<div class="myflex">
<div class="my-inner-item">my image will be here </div>
<div class="my-space-between"></div>
<div class="my-inner-item">my text will be here</div>

</div>
```

Comment: please accept my answers if you think this is helpful.